# Attempted to format MicroSD card, card became inaccessible, is the card trashed?

Tags: windows-8, mac, formatting, filesystem-corruption, micro-sd-card

I attempted to format a brand new Class 4 8 GB Unirex MicroSD card using a USB adapter to my Windows computer using SDFormatter v4.0.

I set the format settings to be Quick format type with Format Size Adjustment turned on. The program told me that it couldn't format the card and after refreshing the Drive list a few times and attempting to format a few more times the MicroSD card disappeared from the list. It also does not appear in Windows Explorer or on my Mac.

I used Windows Disk Management and the disk check from the administrative command prompt and the MicroSD doesn't appear in either of those locations either.

What happened? Is there anything I should attempt? How do I fix the MicroSD card? Is it trashed?

Comment: You need to verify that your SDcard reader is suitable for capacities greater than 2GB, e.g. SDHC and SDXC capable.  This was a problem I had a few years ago when buying USB SDcard readers.

Comment: @sawdust How should I verify that the SDcard reader is SDHC and SDXC capable?

Answer (score 0):

I got the MicroSD card working again by putting it into a camera and formatting the card there. For some reason that got it re-readable and was able to format it on my computer using a MicroSD to SD adapter. The MicroSD to USB adapter was shoddy and still doesn't work, and I suspect it was what caused the corruption in the first place.